# Cannot read global configuration string

Tags: typescript, pulumi

I am using Pulumi's typescript SDK to set up azure infrastructure for my project. I have been trying to get some configuration values in my `index.ts`, as shown in the following code:

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
const config = new pulumi.Config();
export const domain = config.require('azure:location')
```

Unfortunately, this code triggers the following error:

```
error: Missing required configuration variable 'my-project:azure:location'
        please set a value using the command `pulumi config set my-project:azure:location <value>`
```

As an additional remark, I am using `azure:location` as an example (there are also other pieces of config I need), so the obvious workaround of getting the location from somewhere else is unfortunately insufficient.

It looks like `config.require` prefixes the config keys with the name of the project. While the constructor of `Config` allows passing an alternative prefix, there seems to be no option to retrieve the key without prepending a prefix. Is there a workaround for this? Am I missing something? Is it a bug?

#### Pulumi files

In case you need more context, here is a minimal version of the pulumi files that I used to trigger this problem:

`Pulumi.yaml`:

```
name: my-project
runtime: nodejs
description: No description
```

`Pulumi.dev.yaml`:

```
config:
  azure:environment: public
  azure:location: WestEurope
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create a config object with `new pulumi.Config()` then pulumi will assume you want the configuration of your project (everything that is prefixed with the project name). If you want the azure configuration, then I think you can do this with an additional config object:

```
const projectConfig = new pulumi.Config();

const azureConfig = new pulumi.Config("azure");
const azureLocation = azureConfig.get("location");
```